# SignalR send from Server console App to client

Tags: c#, console-application, signalr-hub

is it even possible to send a message to all(or selected) connected clients connected to the hub? I mean from the server side to all clients. I can get clients data to server window, but when I enter and try to send from server side nothing happens on clients window. How to push notifications to all straight from server app?

Server:

```
namespace SignalRHub
{


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
                Console.ReadLine();

                while (true)
                {
                    // get text to send
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your message:");
                    string line = Console.ReadLine();

                    // Get hub context 
                    IHubContext ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();

                    // call addMessage on all clients of context
                    ctx.Clients.All.addMessage(line);

                    // pause to allow clients to receive
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }
        }

        class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                app.MapSignalR();

            }
        }

        [HubName("TestHub")]
        public class TestHub : Hub
        {
            public void SendMsg(string message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Client:

```
namespace SignalRClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHubProxy _hub;

             string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to: " +url);

                var connection = new HubConnection(url);
                _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
                connection.Start().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("---------- Connection OK.");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("------------ Connection FAILED: ");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }




            string line = null;
            while ((line = System.Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                _hub.Invoke("SendMsg", line).Wait();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes what you want to do is possible with SignalR.  You need to add some code client-side that explicitly creates registers a callback for the `Clients.All.` call you have server-side.  Something like: `_hub.on('addMessage', function(line) {
    console.log(line);
});`

Comment: Thanks, as I understand client side has to be somehow subscribed to servers side method which pushes notifications? Could you please give a code example which I could use in actual client? Is this the only way or may be there is a way to force push to all of them like do "console.writeline("bla bla") to all clients", and then message appears in their console, they want it or not! possible?

Comment: Refer to the following MSDN page for some examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: All examples on internet is for webforms only...

Comment: @VytAutas, yes, I found the same and it's very annoying to see everything web centric.